Distribution densities of random variables for normal and exponential laws.

Random variables $\xi_{1}$ and $\xi_{2}$ are independent and have exponential distribution laws with parameters 1 and 3, respectively. Find the distribution density of the random variable.

My solution:
$f_{\frac{x}{y}}(z)=3\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-3y}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\delta(z-\frac{x}{y})e^{-x}dxdy=$
$t=z-\frac{x}{y}$, $dt=-\frac{dx}{y}$, $0\rightarrow z$, $+\infty\rightarrow-\infty$, $x=y(z-t)$
$=-3\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-3y}y\int_{z}^{-\infty}\delta(t)e^{-(z-t)y}dtdy=$
$\int_{a}^{b}\delta(x-x_{0})f(x)dx=f(x_{0})$, $x_{0}\in[a,b]$
$f(t)=e^{-(z-t)y}$, $\int_{-\infty}^{z}\delta(t)e^{-(z-t)y}dt=f(0)=e^{-zy}$, $z\geqslant0$
$=3\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(z+3)y}ydy=\frac{-3}{z+3}(e^{-(z+3)y}y|_{0}^{+\infty}-\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(z+3)y}dy)=$
$e^{-(z+3)y}y|_{0}^{+\infty}=0$
$=-\frac{-3}{-(z+3)^{2}}e^{-(z+3)y}|_{0}^{+\infty}=-\frac{3}{(z+3)^{2}}$
Answer: $-\frac{3}{(z+3)^{2}}$ for $z\geqslant0$.
Check: $-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{3dz}{(z+3)^{2}}=3\frac{1}{z+3}|_{0}^{\infty}=1$

Random variables $\xi_{1}$ and $\xi_{2}$ are independent and have a standard normal distribution. Find the distribution density of the random variable $\frac{\xi_{1}}{|\xi_{2}|}$.

My solution:
$f_{\frac{x}{y}}(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(z-\frac{x}{|y|})e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})}dxdy=$
$t=z-\frac{x}{|y|}$, $-\infty\rightarrow\infty$, $\infty\rightarrow-\infty$, $x=y(z-t)$
$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t)e^{-\frac{1}{2}((y(z-t))^{2}+y^{2})}|y|dtdy=$
$\int_{a}^{b}\delta(x-x_{0})f(x)dx=f(x_{0})$, $x_{0}\in[a,b]$
$f(t)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}((y(z-t))^{2}+y^{2})}$, $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t)e^{-\frac{1}{2}((y(z-t))^{2}+y^{2})}dt=f(0)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}(z^{2}+1)}$
$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|y|e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}(z^{2}+1)}dy=\frac{1}{2\pi}(-\int_{-\infty}^{0}ye^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}(z^{2}+1)}dy+\int_{0}^{+\infty}ye^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}(z^{2}+1)}dy)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{-2}{2(z^{2}+1)}(e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}(z^{2}+1)}|_{0}^{-\infty}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}(z^{2}+1)}|_{0}^{+\infty})=\frac{-1}{2\pi(z^{2}+1)}(-1-1)=\frac{1}{\pi(z^{2}+1)}$
Answer: $\frac{1}{\pi(z^{2}+1)}$ for $z\in R$.
Check: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{\pi(z^{2}+1)}=\frac{1}{\pi}arctg(x)|_{-\infty}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{\pi}(\frac{\pi}{2}-(-\frac{\pi}{2}))=1$
Updated my solutions, correcting errors. Now the obtained densities satisfy the basic property of density.


You missed a minus sign when subbing in $x=y(z-t)$ in the exponential.
Your error is in calculating the final antiderivative, in particular how to deal with the $|y|$. Hint: you need to split the integral in half.


Thanks for checking! Errors corrected.


Random variables $\xi_{1}$ and $\xi_{2}$ are independent and have exponential distribution laws with parameters 1 and 3, respectively. Find the distribution density of the random variable.

My solution:
$f_{\frac{x}{y}}(z)=3\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-3y}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\delta(z-\frac{x}{y})e^{-x}dxdy=$
$t=z-\frac{x}{y}$, $dt=-\frac{dx}{y}$, $0\rightarrow z$, $+\infty\rightarrow-\infty$, $x=y(z-t)$
$=-3\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-3y}y\int_{z}^{-\infty}\delta(t)e^{-(z-t)y}dtdy=$
$\int_{a}^{b}\delta(x-x_{0})f(x)dx=f(x_{0})$, $x_{0}\in[a,b]$
$f(t)=e^{-(z-t)y}$, $\int_{-\infty}^{z}\delta(t)e^{-(z-t)y}dt=f(0)=e^{-zy}$, $z\geqslant0$
$=3\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(z+3)y}ydy=\frac{-3}{z+3}(e^{-(z+3)y}y|_{0}^{+\infty}-\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(z+3)y}dy)=$
$e^{-(z+3)y}y|_{0}^{+\infty}=0$
$=-\frac{-3}{-(z+3)^{2}}e^{-(z+3)y}|_{0}^{+\infty}=-\frac{3}{(z+3)^{2}}$
Answer: $-\frac{3}{(z+3)^{2}}$ for $z\geqslant0$.
Check: $-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{3dz}{(z+3)^{2}}=3\frac{1}{z+3}|_{0}^{\infty}=1$

Random variables $\xi_{1}$ and $\xi_{2}$ are independent and have a standard normal distribution. Find the distribution density of the random variable $\frac{\xi_{1}}{|\xi_{2}|}$.

My solution:
$f_{\frac{x}{y}}(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(z-\frac{x}{|y|})e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})}dxdy=$
$t=z-\frac{x}{|y|}$, $-\infty\rightarrow\infty$, $\infty\rightarrow-\infty$, $x=y(z-t)$
$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t)e^{-\frac{1}{2}((y(z-t))^{2}+y^{2})}|y|dtdy=$
$\int_{a}^{b}\delta(x-x_{0})f(x)dx=f(x_{0})$, $x_{0}\in[a,b]$
$f(t)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}((y(z-t))^{2}+y^{2})}$, $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(t)e^{-\frac{1}{2}((y(z-t))^{2}+y^{2})}dt=f(0)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}(z^{2}+1)}$
$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|y|e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}(z^{2}+1)}dy=\frac{1}{2\pi}(-\int_{-\infty}^{0}ye^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}(z^{2}+1)}dy+\int_{0}^{+\infty}ye^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}(z^{2}+1)}dy)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{-2}{2(z^{2}+1)}(e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}(z^{2}+1)}|_{0}^{-\infty}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2}(z^{2}+1)}|_{0}^{+\infty})=\frac{-1}{2\pi(z^{2}+1)}(-1-1)=\frac{1}{\pi(z^{2}+1)}$
Answer: $\frac{1}{\pi(z^{2}+1)}$ for $z\in R$.
Check: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{\pi(z^{2}+1)}=\frac{1}{\pi}arctg(x)|_{-\infty}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{\pi}(\frac{\pi}{2}-(-\frac{\pi}{2}))=1$
Updated my solutions, correcting errors. Now the obtained densities satisfy the basic property of density.
